# アプリを閉じている間のみサービスを起動する方法について

Tags: android, java

現在開いている画面(MainActivity)から戻るやホームボタンを押して他のことをしている間のみサービスを起動して一定時間ごとに通知を行いたいです
再び、アプリに戻った際はサービスを停止するといった感じです。
方法など知っている方がいましたらよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

単純に
Activity.onPause()の中でstartService()を実行
Activity.onResume()の中でstopService()を実行
ではダメでしょうか？

※話が多少それますが、
　startService()はAndroidのシステムから自動的に終了させされる可能性があります。
　startForeground()を使用すればかなりのシーンで自動的な終了を抑止できますが、
　Notificationにserviceが起動中である旨が表示されます。